# Android - Button text center gravity not working

Tags: android, android-layout, button, textview, android-button

I have this XML layout in my App (example of one button):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollViewMain"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff0e8" >

    ///some views       

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnVysledkySportka"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chckSprotka"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/chckSprotka"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/chckSprotka"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:background="#ffe118"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="vysledkySportka"
        android:text="Archiv výsledků"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

 ///some views    
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

But when I start my app at Android 4.3, the text of buttons isn´t in center of button. Look at the screenshot (in red rectangle):

[image]

Where can be problem?

**EDIT:**

[Whole layout](http://pastebin.com/d59UTvCM)

Comment: try button gravity as center vertical and center horizontal as well..

Comment: try android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Comment: you have 4buttons, are they having the same id? check that too

Comment: no, they have unique id...I upload whole layout, look at it...I try set gravity as center vertical and center horizontal but nothing help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify:

```
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chckSprotka"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/chckSprotka"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/chckSprotka"
```

It does make the bottom/right/top edge of your button match the bottom edge of the given anchor view ID & accommodates bottom/right/top margin, ***but*** while doing that, the `android_gravity` does not take the resultant height/width into consideration.

So the `gravity` of the `text` is `center` according to `wrap_content` for `layout_height` and `layout_width`.

You can verify that by setting values for `layout_height` and `layout_width` (Eg. 200dp and 100dp to try with) and you will get the `text` with gravity `center` but for that height and width.

To confirm the same, what you can do is use a container `LinearLayout` for your `Button` like:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chckStastnych"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/chckStastnych"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/chckStastnych"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:background="#ffe118" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnVysledkyStastnych"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#ffe118"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="vysledkyStastnych"
                android:text="Archiv výsledků"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Set the `gravity` of `LinearLayout` as `center` and then `center` the `Button` within or as shown above, use `layout_gravity` for the button to `center` it in parent `LinearLayout`.
This will work as a solution when you do that for all 4 buttons, however there might be better options if you restructure your xml and avoid this kind of nesting.

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnVysledkySportka"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chckSprotka"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/chckSprotka"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/chckSprotka"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:background="#ffe118"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="vysledkySportka"
            android:text="Archiv výsledků"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: You havent changed android:gravity="center" to             android:gravity="center_vertical"

Comment: I tried it, but the text wasn´t in the center of button.